# Convert between X.509 and PKCS#1 RSA Public keys

Tags: flutter, encryption, rsa, crypto++

I am using CryptoPP to generate RSA keys, and run encryption / decryption of large amounts of data. Because of this, I am deciding to input data through a web socket from a phone app (currently using flutter), along with already in place desktop clients (the desktop clients work as they support the format the server uses).

My issue is that the keys are in different formats, everything I try (specifically [simple_rsa](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_rsa)) fails to be compatible with the server. As flutter only supports `PKCS#1` as far as I am aware.

I understand now that the public key is formatted with `X.509` from [crypto++ wiki](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats#Public_Key_Format), and through use of an online tool [this](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/rsa-encryption-decryption) I have found that the cipher type (I'm guessing padding?) is `OAEP with SHA-1`.

These show that both key types are encoded with `ASN.1`

For reference, the server code is very similar to [this](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Encryption_Schemes#RSA_Encryption_Scheme_.28OAEP_and_SHA.29), but uses a key size of `4096`

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Generate keys
AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

InvertibleRSAFunction parameters;
parameters.GenerateRandomWithKeySize( rng, 1536 );

RSA::PrivateKey privateKey( parameters );
RSA::PublicKey publicKey( parameters );
```

And the key is written to a `.pem` file by encoding the data in base64.

```
std::string base64 = macaron::Base64::Encode(pubKeyString);
std::string base64LineLength;
int i = 0;
while (i < base64.size()) {
     if (i % 64 == 0 && i)
          base64LineLength.push_back('\n');
     base64LineLength.push_back(base64[i]);
     i++;
}
base64LineLength = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" + base64LineLength + "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
std::ofstream pubkeyOut("secure_chat_rsa.pub");
pubkeyOut << base64LineLength;
pubkeyOut.close();
```

Also, this is an example of a public key with the formatting (`X.509`)

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Edit:
I have tried putting the key through an `ANS.1` decoder, and extracted the bit string from it, then put that through a base64 encoder to give:

```
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
```

However, this is not a valid RSA key. (from trying to encrypt with it)

I have 4 main questions:

- Is there a way for the `X.509` format to be converted to `PKCS#1` and vice versa
- If converted, will the output be compatible. When the server encodes data, will the client be able to decrypt it if the keys are converted?
- Is there a way for flutter to work with `X.509` formatted keys?
- If this is only due to `ANS.1`, how exactly would you go about encoding ciphers or keys?

Comment: Looks like a valid key to me. The public exponent (value 17) is somewhat strange. What error do you get? Maybe you just require a header and footer line? In that case replace  `RSA PUBLIC KEY` for `PUBLIC KEY`

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I haven't managed to try the key on the phone app yet, but the error that gets thrown when using the extracted key is a general invalid key error. The same as if I use "hello" as a key

Comment: Try the header and footer line trick to make a valid PEM file out of it. I would be surprised if you need it as binary DER file but that's also possible (just decode the base 64 in that case). If you're unlucky the public exponent is the problem.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have managed to test it on the server, and it throws BERDecodeError. This only happened with the stripped key, so I think the key must need some sort of header which was taken out when decoded with `ANS.1`. I have also just used the raw string to avoid any loading errors

Comment: DER is a form of DER, it probably reqeuires the binary encoded key, otherwise it may try  and decode the text, which will of course fail. Sorry, I had to sleep :)

Comment: I think you are looking for below answer. Open the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/75395621/6607074