# [Flutter]: How to get public key PEM string from the x509 certificate PEM string

Tags: flutter, dart, x509certificate, x509

I need the way to extract PEM string of Public Key from the x509 certificate PEM string.
Now i'm using [basic_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils) package, that can generate x509Certificate object from the giving PEM string.
This x509Certificate object have `publicKeyData` field that has `bytes` field, that represents the public key bytes as String.
However i cannot use this `bytes` to generate valid PEM string of public key.

So question is - how can i extract public key as PEM string from the certificate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For RSA public keys:

```dart
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';
import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';

final bytes = hex.decode(cert.publicKeyData.bytes!);
final key = CryptoUtils.rsaPublicKeyFromDERBytes(Uint8List.fromList(bytes));
final pem = CryptoUtils.encodeRSAPublicKeyToPemPkcs1(key);
```

The `Pkcs1` version of the encoder will bracket the PEM with `BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY` whereas the non-pkcs1 version will use `BEGIN PUBLIC KEY`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'll try

Answer (score 0):

In Java Encryption

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

public static String encrypt(String request) {
    try {
        String publicKeyString = null;

        publicKeyString = "YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY_GOES_HERE==";

        PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKey(publicKeyString);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(request.getBytes()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception" + e);
        
        return e.toString();
    }
}
public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String base64PublicKey) {
    PublicKey publicKey = null;
    try {
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64PublicKey.getBytes()));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
        return publicKey;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception, " + e);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception, " + e);
    }
    return publicKey;
}
```

Converted Java encryption format to Flutter/dart

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';

encryptString(String plainText) async {
    var modulusBytes = base64.decode(
        "YOUR_PUBLIC_GOES_HERE");

    final key =
        CryptoUtils.rsaPublicKeyFromDERBytes(Uint8List.fromList(modulusBytes));
    final pem = CryptoUtils.encodeRSAPublicKeyToPemPkcs1(key);
    final publicKey = RSAKeyParser().parse(pem) as RSAPublicKey;

    final encrypter = Encrypter(
      RSA(publicKey: publicKey, encoding: RSAEncoding.PKCS1),
    );

    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText);

    return encrypted.base64;    
}
```